# Momentum vs adaptive step methods

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, adagrad

My understanding is that:

- With **momentum**, one can avoid e.g. "zig-zags" during gradient decent by averaging gradients to determine a better ***direction*** of descent.
- With **adaptive step size methods** like **AdaGrad** and **RMSProp** one accumulates gradients and uses a norm of this accumulated gradient to use a larger or smaller ***step size*** per dimension to pay more attention to sparse features.

On the surface of it, these methods seem to do different things by changing **direction** vs **step sizes (per dimension)**, but aren't the concepts of direction and the step size **per dimension** related? Moreover, don't they **both** accumulate gradients?

- For example, when we accumulate gradients to decide the **step size** for each dimension, isn't that technically **mathematically equivalent** to changing the ***direction*** of descent as well?
- Or put another way, couldn't one argue that **momentum** can be reinterpreted as a method that uses a different step size per dimension based on the accumulated (averaged) gradient?